# How to run several queries in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE TableR = '1';
INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '1', 'test1');
INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '2', 'test2');
INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '3', 'test3');
```

For connect we use code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($this->MysqlHost,$this->MysqlUser,$this->MysqlPassword,$this->MysqlDatabase);
$result = $mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = $mysqli->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
$result = $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Now we need use several query for run all query.

But i would be like run only one query, ie:

```
$query = "
        DELETE FROM Table WHERE TableR = '1';
        INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '1', 'test1');
        INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '2', 'test2');
        INSERT INTO Table (TableR, Seet, Keyword) VALUES ('1', '3', 'test3');
    ";
```

Tell me please how to run several queries in a single query ?

Comment: @PeterMmm we use mysqli..

Comment: @Kermani why nee use left joing anf other ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($query);
```

*Enjoy!*

Answer (score 1):

With multiquery?

You can check the following documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

If you are trying to insert multiple rows, you can check:

[Batch insertion of data to MySQL database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042461/batch-insertion-of-data-to-mysql-database-using-php)

(look for LOAD DATA INFILE solution...)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

If you use it, be careful about security.

Example #1 Multiple Statements

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1); ";
$sql.= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
?>
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_num"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_num"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please summarize the content of the URL in your answer, so if the link goes offline the answer will still be useful.